# CSS Wrap Giving Page White Border

Tags: css

When I apply this code to my CSS (which is a wrap that goes around my entire page for CMS purposes), the entire page gets a white border of abour 5-10px.

```
#wrap {position:relative;width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0}
```

http://www.brockpatterson.com/secret.php

Thanks,
Drummer

Comment: Can you post a test page or more code so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset your default html elements to achieve the effect you're looking for;

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I'd also suggest you use a [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) sheet.

Comment: I'll look into those!  I've been seeing people use those alot now.

Comment: @drummer392 I really suggest you do, they're made to fix issues such as this, where your design gets hampered by the default stylings of the HTML elements.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Eric Meyer's CSS Reset sheet. It is now widely used and incorporated into full HTML templates like http://html5boilerplate.com

Answer (score 1):

Thats one annoying default behaviour of pretty much all browsers, you can fix it by using:

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it would be simple.  Don't know why I didn't try that.  I've never had that problem before! lol